# How to cut everything to first occurence of letter N

Tags: bash

How to cut everything, what is before N_NNN:

```
SPA-8   N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2
```

Between SPA-8 and N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2 there are 3 whitespaces

As output I would like to get:

```
N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2
```

Answer (score 4):

give this sed one-liner a try

```
sed 's/[^N]*//'
```

Comment: It answers the question from the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
awk -F"N_NNN" '{print FS$2 }'
```

which gives

```
awk -F"N_NNN" '{print FS$2 }' <<< "SPA-8   N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2"
# N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2
```

If you can split on the whitespace, you can do

```
awk -F"   " '{print $2 }'
```

Comment: In fact, if you want to split on space you can also do `cut -d' ' -f4- <<< "SPA-8   N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2"`.

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking about including cut as well ;). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that :

```
$ echo "SPA-8   N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2" | awk -F"N\_NNN" '{print "N\_NNN"$2}'
N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure BASH way of achieving this task:

```
s='SPA-8   N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2'
[[ "$s" =~ (N_NNN.*$) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
N_NNN4_1.2.3.4.zzzzzzz_bbb.nnn2
```